# Could the integral be calculated by complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

The following integral seems to be related to a complex integration:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}e^s\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)ds.
$$
However, the upper end is $1$ instead of $+\infty$ in which case usually can be dealt with a Cauchy integral. Please give me some help or hints. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the integration formula $$\int e^x[f(x)+f'(x)] dx=e^x f(x),$$ which comes by integration by parts. Then $$\int_{0}^{1}e^s\left( \frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2} \right) ds=\frac{e^s}{s}|_{0}^{1}=-\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is equal to $-\infty$ since
$$
\int_0^1e^s({1\over s}-{1\over s^2})ds{\le \int_0^1{1\over s}-{1\over s^2}ds
\\=\ln |s|+{1\over s}\Big|_0^1
\\=-\infty
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int e^s\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\,ds=\frac{e^s}{s}$$
$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1}e^s\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2}\right)\,ds=e-\frac{e^{\epsilon }}{\epsilon }$$